# Can Cookies Time Out before (or exactly when) the browser receives them?

Tags: java, html, tomcat, cookies

The setup here is a client browser making a request to a Tomcat server.

The user makes the request to a servlet, then the servlet creates a cookie with a 2 minute timeout.  The servlet does some extensive processing after setting the cookie which can take more than two minutes (and does not return output till the server is done processing).  My question is, if the processing takes more than two minutes, can the cookie time out before even reaching the browser?  Or does the timeout for the cookie happen on the browser side once the client receives it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both.

By sending an expired cookie from the server to the client, you are telling the client to delete the cookie. Which is the way cookies are normally deleted programmatically.

So it is possible to create a cookie, set an expiration date. Then do some other processing. Then when the headers are finally sent, the cookie is sent - but sent with a date which has expired.

Comment: I just realized I got confused because the Java Cookie class lets you specify the time as "2 minutes from now", but what is actually happening is that Java translates that time into an actual time-stamp which is then sent to the client.